# No subpixel smoothing in MathJax

Tags: support, mathjax

I have no subpixel smoothing in MathJax, in FireFox 28, 29 and IE 11 under Windows 7. Prevuously all was OK. I suspect this happened due to a Windows update. In other texts in FireFox and systemwide the smoothing is OK. What should I do to fix MathJax appearance?

This does not depend on browser: the same happens in IE and Chrome.

Comment: Do you have an image that illustrates what is happening?

Comment: @robjohn I think itb is quite clearv what I said: no subpixel hinting in MathJax, which was there before.

Comment: I didn't say that your statement was unclear; I asked if you had an image. It would be helpful for those of us that cannot reproduce the problem.

Comment: @robjohn html-css renderer: http://storage9.static.itmages.ru/i/14/0404/h_1396617232_7366232_412298da46.png mathml renderer: http://storage5.static.itmages.ru/i/14/0404/h_1396617267_3452932_e21f9b232a.png If to disable font downloading in Firefox, then the subpixel rendering appears in MathML, but with barely suitable font, and html-css fallbacks to SVG after a long pause.

Comment: @robjohn if to disable downloadable fonts, then subpixel in mathml works, but the font used is far from perfect: http://storage9.static.itmages.ru/i/14/0404/h_1396617779_7607277_ceb0dc1550.png, html-css just does not work.

Comment: There does seem to be subpixel smoothing applied, however, the font substitution is bad (e.g. choosing a bitmap font) or possibly the font hinting is not operating properly. This does sound like an OS issue.

Comment: @robjohn subpixel smoothing is applied only outside of MathJax.

Comment: Yes. Subpixel smoothing is applied by the OS when it renders the fonts. The problem could be in the fonts requested by MathJax (which would affect a large number of users) or in how the OS fills font requests (font substitution) or in how the font renderer handles the hints (for an outline font).  This is why I said this looks like an OS problem. In your question, you mention a Windows update. Was anything else about the fonts in your system altered?

Comment: @last days I was trying to install a scanner, I did not change anything else.

Comment: @robjohn I downloaded the MathJax and Stix fonts used by MathJax  in otf format and they seem not to be subpixel-smoothed even locally, in preview and in LibreOffice. Possibly MathJax updated their fonts recently to those which do not have a TTF outline?

Comment: @robjohn under another (new) user all is OK, subpixel smoothing in MathJax works well.

Comment: The STIX fonts installed on my system are PostScript Type 1. MathJax uses the fonts installed on your computer. As configured on MSE, the preferred MathJax font is "TeX", but "STIX" will be used in its absence.

Comment: @robjohn I fixed the problem by creating a new user account and deleting the old one. This took me one day to transfer all settings and data.

Comment: Ah, then the problem may have been in your MathJax preferences that are stored in cookies. You might try resetting your cookies for this site in the other account with the problem. Start with the mjx.menu cookie. Oh, you've already deleted the other account? Well, for next time.

Comment: @robjohn I have already tried deleting all cookies.